# JSF reloading ViewParam after commandButton action

Tags: jsf, primefaces, converters

I'm using JSF and Primefaces. I have an edit.xhtml page with a f:viewParam receiving an entity id:

```
<f:viewParam name="id" value="#{backingBean.entity}" converter="entityConverter" />
```

I have two commandButton, one to submit and save the entity:

```
<p:commandButton ajax="false" value="#{bundle.save}" 
action="#{backingBean.save()}"/>
```

Another to add an item to a collection of the entity:

```
<p:commandButton ajax="true" process="@this" value="#{bundle.add}" 
actionListener="#{backingBean.addItem()}" />
```

This is my BackingBean:

```
@ViewScoped 
@Named("backingBean")
public class BackingBean {
  @EJB
  MyDAO myDAO;

  private Entity entity; //with getters and setters

  public void addItem() {
    entity.getData().add(new Item()); //another entity object
  }

  public void save(){
    myDAO.save(entity);
  }
...
}
```

Also I have an EntityConverter class that invoques the DAO and load the object:

```
@Override
public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
    try {
        return myDAO.findById(Entity.class, Long.valueOf(value));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

If I try to add more than one items or if I click on save button, the Entity in the BackingBean class is reloaded by calling the getAsObject method of the converter class.

What I'm doing wrong? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For clarity the normal f:param will always behave that way.  I use in all my projects [OmniFaces ViewParam](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/components/viewParam) which fixes these issues.

**Stateless mode to avoid unnecessary conversion, validation and model updating on postbacks**

> The standard UIViewParameter implementation calls the model setter
>   again after postback. This is not always desired when being bound to a
>   view scoped bean and can lead to performance problems when combined
>   with an expensive converter. To solve this, this component by default
>   stores the submitted value as a component property instead of in the
>   model (and thus in the view state in case the binding is to a view
>   scoped bean).
>
> The standard UIViewParameter implementation calls the converter and
>   validators again on postbacks. This is not always desired when you
>   have e.g. a required="true", but the parameter is not retained on form
>   submit. You would need to retain it on every single command
>   link/button by . To solve this, this component doesn't call
>   the converter and validators again on postbacks.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I'll implement omnifaces